# Chip tags not removing with Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, tags

I am trying to create an input with words as tags and then allow the user to remove them. Every time the X is clicked, I am getting an error saying

> ReferenceError: remove is not defined

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm using the below code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="ingredients">
  <ul id="list"></ul>
  <input type="text" id="ingredients" placeholder="type and Enter ...">
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var txt = document.getElementById('ingredients');
var list = document.getElementById('list');
var items = ['PHP', 'React.js', 'WordPress'];

txt.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
  if (e.key === 'Enter') {
    let val = txt.value;
    if (val !== '') {
      if (items.indexOf(val) >= 0) {
        alert('Tag name is a duplicate');
      } else {
        items.push(val);
        render();
        txt.value = '';
        txt.focus();
      }
    } else {
      alert('Please type a tag Name');
    }
  }
});

function render() {
  list.innerHTML = '';
  items.map((item, index) => {
    list.innerHTML += `<li><span>${item}</span><a href="javascript: remove(${index})">X</a></li>`;
  });
}

function remove(i) {
  items = items.filter(item => items.indexOf(item) != i);
  render();
}

window.onload = function() {
  render();
  txt.focus();
}
```

Comment: I don't know what went wrong in there, when I pasted same code in here. It works perfectly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IT LOOKS LIKE ORDERING ISSUE. For safe side, u can use an object to store global function. An instead of using href use onclick.

```
    function remove(i) {
      items = items.filter(item => items.indexOf(item) != i);
      render();
    }
    function render() {
  list.innerHTML = '';
  items.map((item, index) => {
    list.innerHTML += `<li><span>${item}</span><a href="javascript: LIB.remove(${index})">X</a></li>`;
  });
}
```

**// All function**

```
window.LIB = {
  remove:remove,
  render: render
}
```

```js
var txt = document.getElementById('ingredients');
var list = document.getElementById('list');
var items = ['PHP', 'React.js', 'WordPress'];

txt.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
  if (e.key === 'Enter') {
    let val = txt.value;
    if (val !== '') {
      if (items.indexOf(val) >= 0) {
        alert('Tag name is a duplicate');
      } else {
        items.push(val);
        render();
        txt.value = '';
        txt.focus();
      }
    } else {
      alert('Please type a tag Name');
    }
  }
});
function remove(i) {
  items = items.filter(item => items.indexOf(item) != i);
  render();
}
function render() {
  list.innerHTML = '';
  items.map((item, index) => {
    list.innerHTML += `<li><span>${item}</span><a href="javascript: void 0" onclick="LIB.remove(${index})">X</a></li>`;
  });
}
window.LIB = {
  remove:remove,
  render: render
}


window.onload = function() {
  render();
  txt.focus();
}
```

```html
<div class="ingredients">
  <ul id="list"></ul>
  <input type="text" id="ingredients" placeholder="type and Enter ...">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to add `ready` function to your javascript file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var txt = document.getElementById('ingredients');
   var list = document.getElementById('list');
   var items = ['PHP', 'React.js', 'WordPress'];
   .......
});
```